# How to pass ArrayList from Adapter to activity?

Tags: android, arraylist

I need send ArrayList list_add to activity but I don't know how I can do it if is possible share it on main activity for use it in the future.
Anyone can help me to implement a method for do it?
below have MainAdatper for recyclerview where I have a list_add and want passed it to main activity and after I can add it to

```
class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static int lastCheckedPos = 0;
    ArrayList<String> list_add = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lista_show;
    private Context context;
    String t;    

    public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> lista_shows, Context context) {
        lista_show = lista_shows;
    }

    @Override
    public MainAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.mdevice.setText (lista_show.get (position));
        holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener (new View.OnLongClickListener () {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                t = lista_show.get(position);
                if (list_add.contains(t)) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext (), t+"Already Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    list_add.add(t);
                    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#60B5EC"));
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext (), t+"Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t = lista_show.get (position);
                holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                if (! list_add.contains(t)) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext (), "Long press for add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    list_add.remove(t);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext (), t+"Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista_show.size ();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mdevice;
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super (itemView);
            mdevice = itemView.findViewById (R.id.device);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById (R.id.mcardview);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add interface for callback:

```java
public interface ListOwner {
  void push(ArrayList<String> list);
}
```

2. Set refernce in adapter:

```java
private ListOwner listOwner;

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> lista_shows, Context context, ListOwner owner) {
  this.lista_show = lista_shows;
  this.listOwner = owner;
}
```

3. The call it in adapter when you need:

```java
if (listOwner != null) {
  listOwner.push(list_add);
}
```

4. Of course, implement `ListOwner` by your activity:

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListOwner {
 // all code

  // create instance of adapter:
  mAdapter = new MainAdapter(list_show, MyActivity.this, MyActivity.this);


  @Override
  public void push(ArrayList<String> list) {
     // you have the list here
  }
}
```

**P.S.**

You can omit interface and pass reference to the `Activity` directly (`MyActivity` in the sample)

Comment: when I try to add this code got error on lista_show in main public MainAdapter(ArrayList<String> lista_shows, Context context, ListOwner owner) {
  // all your code
  this.listOwner = owner;
}

Comment: @Developers, what error do you get? (see updated answer, pt. 2 as well)

Comment: @Developers, 1) what approach (with or without interface) do you use? 2) how do you instantiate the adapter?

Comment: mRecicleView = findViewById (R.id.Reclycler_View);
                                    mRecicleView.setHasFixedSize (true);
                                    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager (dasboard.this,2);
                                    mAdapter = new MainAdapter(lista_show, dasboard.this);
                                    mRecicleView.setLayoutManager (mLayoutManager);
                                    mRecicleView.setAdapter (mAdapter);
                                    runanimation(mRecicleView,0);

Comment: @Developers, if you add parameter to adapter's constructor, you should pass actual argument from calling code: `mAdapter = new MainAdapterlista_show, dashboard.this, dashboard.this)` (I suppose, `dashboard` is your activity) - see pt 4.

Comment: if I want to use setOnClickListener? for add the list_add to my database?thanks for your helping.